# Mongoose $lookup in same collection doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following dataset, where I have two types of objects discriminate by the field `lType` that can be either `base` or `extra`. extra has a ref to a `base` location.

```json
    [
            {
                "_id": "622b6f1c7a0aca9aa252756c",
                "country": "US",
                "county": "Florida",
                "city": "Miami",
                "lType": "base",
                "displayString": "Florida,Miami",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "622b6f1d7a0aca9aa252756e",
                "landmark": "Gas station",
                "baseLocation": "622b6f1c7a0aca9aa252756c",
                "lType": "extra",
                "displayString": "Florida,Miami,Gas station",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "622b6f4c5d0fe602a18826a7",
                "country": "US",
                "county": "Florida",
                "city": "Tampa",
                "lType": "base",
                "displayString": "Florida,Tampa",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "622b6f4c5d0fe602a18826a9",
                "landmark": "Downtown",
                "baseLocation": "622b6f4c5d0fe602a18826a7",
                "lType": "extra",
                "displayString": "Florida,Tampa,Downtown",
                "__v": 0
            }
    ]
```

When I try to do an aggregation lookup like this

```js
    const location = await Location.collection.aggregate([{
      $lookup: {
        from: 'location',
        localField: 'baseLocation',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'locationData'
      }
    }]).toArray();
```

I get an empty array in `locationData` for my `extra` locations even though my `baseLocation` field is an ObjectId pointing to a `base` location object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo. Instead of `from: 'location'`, it should be `from: 'locations'`.

Try to change your code like this:

```js
const location = await Location.collection.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'locations',
    localField: 'baseLocation',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'locationData'
  }
}]);
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T4l4Uqnl8zO)

Comment: well dang,  I never know when to use plural when working with mongo, lol. Thanks !

Comment: When you have to specify the name of the collection in `aggregate` query, you should use plural names because Mongo creates collections with plural names.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need more "depth" linking locations, you could use `"$graphLookup"`.

[Finds the Candy Machine at the Gas Station.]

```js
db.locations.aggregate([
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "locations",
      "startWith": "$baseLocation",
      "connectFromField": "baseLocation",
      "connectToField": "_id",
      "as": "locationData"
    }
  }
])
```

Try  it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8W-HWOfiybZ).